# SQL: How do I show all Items in Inventory and Sum sales of items sold in a time period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to find all items on hand from `@Supplier_ID` and summarize any sales since `@Begin_Date`. What is returned are all items on hand that have never been sold and those sold since `@Begin_Date`. Items on hand that were sold *before* `@Begin_Date` are excluded from the results. How do I fix that?

I am using SQL Server 2012 and SSRS v3.

```
SELECT DISTINCT        
    inventory_supplier.supplier_id AS [Supp ID], 
    address.name AS Supplier, 
    inv_loc.location_id AS [Inventory Loc ID],
    inv_mast.item_id AS [Item ID], 
    inv_mast.item_desc AS [Item Desc],
    inv_loc.qty_on_hand AS QOH,
    inv_loc.moving_average_cost AS MAC,
    invoice_line.qty_shipped,
    invoice_hdr.customer_id AS [Customer ID], 
    invoice_hdr.bill2_name AS Customer,
    oe_line.source_loc_id AS [Sales Source Loc]
FROM            
    inventory_supplier 
INNER JOIN 
    inv_mast ON inventory_supplier.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid 
INNER JOIN 
    address ON inventory_supplier.supplier_id = address.id 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    invoice_line ON inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = invoice_line.inv_mast_uid 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    inv_loc ON inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    invoice_hdr ON invoice_line.invoice_no = invoice_hdr.invoice_no 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    oe_line ON invoice_hdr.order_no = oe_line.order_no 
            AND invoice_line.inv_mast_uid = oe_line.inv_mast_uid
WHERE        
    (inventory_supplier.supplier_id = @Supplier_ID) 
    AND (invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date
         OR invoice_hdr.invoice_date IS NULL) 
    AND (inv_loc.qty_on_hand > 0)
ORDER BY  
    [Item ID], [Inventory Loc ID], [Customer ID], [Sales Source Loc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your `invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date` to your join statement

```
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    invoice_hdr ON invoice_line.invoice_no = invoice_hdr.invoice_no 
        AND invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date
```

Don't see a lot of `FULL OUTER JOIN`s.  Sure you don't want `LEFT JOIN` here?

You might want to separate out the Invoice information from the Inventory information into a subquery, and LEFT JOIN to the Invoice information.

```
SELECT DISTINCT        
    inventory_supplier.supplier_id AS [Supp ID], 
    address.name AS Supplier, 
    inv_loc.location_id AS [Inventory Loc ID],
    inv_mast.item_id AS [Item ID], 
    inv_mast.item_desc AS [Item Desc],
    inv_loc.qty_on_hand AS QOH,
    inv_loc.moving_average_cost AS MAC,
    invoices.qty_shipped,
    invoices.customer_id AS [Customer ID], 
    invoices.bill2_name AS Customer,
    invoices.source_loc_id AS [Sales Source Loc]
FROM            
    inventory_supplier 
INNER JOIN 
    inv_mast ON inventory_supplier.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid 
INNER JOIN 
    address ON inventory_supplier.supplier_id = address.id 
INNER JOIN 
    inv_loc ON inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
          invoice_line.inv_mast_uid,  
          invoice_line.qty_shipped,
          invoice_hdr.customer_id, 
          invoice_hdr.bill2_name,
          oe_line.source_loc_id
     FROM 
          invoice_line
          INNER JOIN 
              invoice_hdr ON invoice_line.invoice_no = invoice_hdr.invoice_no 
          INNER JOIN 
              oe_line ON invoice_hdr.order_no = oe_line.order_no 
              AND invoice_line.inv_mast_uid = oe_line.inv_mast_uid
     WHERE
          invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date
    ) invoices ON invoices.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid
WHERE        
    inventory_supplier.supplier_id = @Supplier_ID 
    AND inv_loc.qty_on_hand > 0
ORDER BY  
    [Item ID], [Inventory Loc ID], [Customer ID], [Sales Source Loc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
WHERE        
(inventory_supplier.supplier_id = @Supplier_ID) 
AND (invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date
                         OR invoice_hdr.invoice_date IS NULL) 
AND (inv_loc.qty_on_hand > 0)
```

to

```
WHERE        
(inventory_supplier.supplier_id = @Supplier_ID) 
AND (invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date) 
AND (inv_loc.qty_on_hand > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are including dates, `invoice_hdr.invoice_date` that are `NULL` in the `WHERE` clause. Simply remove it:

```
WHERE        
(inventory_supplier.supplier_id = @Supplier_ID) 
AND (invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= @Begin_Date) 
AND (inv_loc.qty_on_hand > 0)
```